# MYSQL select only 1 from 5 same values

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I want to get one value out of 5 which are the same, lets say 5 records have the same value in some column.

How do I only get one out of them and not 5 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT` to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table;
```

Comment: What if you wanna use what? Sorry, didn't get your question.

Comment: was asking how to select * and not a field, i figured its SELECT DISTINCT *, am i right ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, although I'm not sure you'll get desirable results :)

Comment: i don't get it, could u provide a short explanation of DISTINCT ? and how to get SELECT * in it?

Comment: If you can elaborate your goal, I can help you better. You want to select each field of the table, only unique values of each?

Comment: You don't need the parentheses. `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`"SELECT * WHERE column = 'Term' ORDER BY column2 LIMIT 1"`

and then a simple while loop to output the data

Comment: Sorry mate, but this is a VERY weird approach to the task :)

Comment: I second it.  Its valid and it works so I don't know what can we critize to it